# Find if value exists in dataset.Table (column 0). if so, get row index and update value in (column 1)

Tags: c#, dataset

I really can´t find an answer to my question, I don't really know what to write to find something about it.

I get an array of numbers with a boolean value. I want to check if each number is in my DataSet. if so I want to check if its boolean is true, if value is false I want to update that value.

```
 foreach (var item in EU)
        {
            if (objDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Any(roww => Convert.ToInt64(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1)) == roww.Field<Int64>(0)))
            {
                if (objDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Any(rowa => true == rowa.Field<bool>(1)))
                {
                    ExistingPhones.Add(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1), true);
                }
                else
                {
                    UpdatePhones.Add(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1), true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ActivePhones.Add(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1), true);
            }
        }
```

I got all sorted out, but the second If statement is extremely slow and exponentially increases runtime. After finding the number in the first if statement, how do I check its boolean value directly?

> P.D: Don´t mind the ".Substring(1, item.Length -1)" that´s because I
>   receive numbers with a plus -> +34666999333 and I need to erase it to
>   store it into the database as a BigInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps in this case using two times the Linq calls to AsEnumerable and Any is not any better than using the old Select method of the DataTable object. In your code you execute two times the mentioned pattern and perhaps this is not 'performance wise'.
You could avoid it using the [DataTable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) method and store the results in an DataRow array.

```
foreach (var item in EU)
{
    string phoneWithoutPlus = item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1);
    var rows = objDataSet.Tables[0].Select("Number = " + phoneWithoutPlus);
    if (rows.Length > 0 && rows[0].Field<bool>(1) == true)
    {
        ExistingPhones.Add(phoneWithoutPlus, true);
    }
    else if (rows.Length > 0 && rows[0].Field<bool>(1) == false)
    {
        UpdatePhones.Add(phoneWithoutPlus, true);
    }
    else
    {
        ActivePhones.Add(phoneWithoutPlus, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I up-voted you because it looks really good, but had to add that phoneWithoutPlus variable so you wouldn't create 3 extra strings

Comment: Big Big huge thankyou, you helped me solve the problem and it works perfectly an the timeload is linear :) :) !! So everytime it takes 4 seconds instead of 4... then 8... then 20...!!

Tho I had to code some things differently and more propperly, I send you an edit!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Any() but get an object using FirstOrDefault() and save it into variable:

```
var myObj = objDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
.Where(roww => Convert.ToInt64(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1)) == roww.Field<Int64>(0))
.FirstOrDefault();

if (myObj != null)
{
    //reuse myObj here
    if (myObj...)
    {
        ExistingPhones.Add(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1), true);
    }
    else
    {
        UpdatePhones.Add(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1), true);
    }
}
else
{
    ActivePhones.Add(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1), true);
}
```

Comment: I didn´t try your solution but the one above solved my issue perfectly, without making the process time consuming

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a dictionary.   The dictionary creates a link between the key and the rows of the datatable without copying the datatable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();

            Dictionary<Int64, DataRow> dict = objDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<Int64>(0), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            foreach (var item in EU)
            {
                Int64 itemKey = Convert.ToInt64(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1));
                if (dict.ContainsKey(itemKey))
                {
                    DataRow row = dict[itemKey];
                    if (row.Field<bool>(1) == true)
                    {
                        ExistingPhones.Add(phoneWithoutPlus, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UpdatePhones.Add(phoneWithoutPlus, true);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ActivePhones.Add(itemKey, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

​
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have dictionaries working (ExistingPhones, UpdatePhones and ActivePhones are dictionaries "Well... they are SortedDictionaries" So what I need is to check against my database records and I want to avoid overusing variables (sometimes I have over 1 million records at once and that takes a big chunk of RAM)

The solution above solved my issue tho :)

Comment: Enumerating through each row of datatable to find item will take forever.  The dictionary approach would be much much quicker.  Compare the times.

Comment: I´ve been trying to keep up with your code, but I don´t fully understand what happens. As far as I get to understand, you create a dictionary out of my dataset.table creating sort of an ID column and filling up a list with phonenumber and boolean as a datarow.
But I cannot understand what is going on inside the foreach loop, if you could develop it further I may understand it.

And sorry I´ve been writing in c# for around 3 weeks now and i´m not a master of the universe yet

Comment: I updated my code to show full example.  My original code only showed how to use the dictionary and didn't show the code to add the phone since other responders answered the question.  I now posted full code.  I think some of the other answers may have errors in the code logic.  You have three cases 1) item key doesn't already exist in table 2) Field 0  is true 3) Field 0 is false.  I assuming each key may have multiple row in table.  I can modify code if each key is unique.

Comment: The time of code should be the time to create dictionary + log() of the time of your old code.  Depending on the number of items in EU and the size of the table will depend on performance improvements.

Comment: Each key is unique, just coded it and it works, now testing execution time. 

But it bugs me not fully understanding how it works, theres a couple wrong  symbols tho, i´m sending you an edit.

Comment: Changed code for unique key.  I thought the code was pretty understandable.   The code creates a dictionary using linq. The Int64 value of item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1) is the key and the value of the dictionary the DataRow.  Then simply looks up the datarow by the int64 value.